# How do I read this engineering drawing for this screw?

Tags: cad, drafting

I am trying to recreate this screw hole in 3D modeling software Siemens NX.

This drawing is from page 4-14 in [MagneMover LITE User’s Manual](http://www.magnemotion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/990000410_MM_LITE_Rev_E.pdf) document.

[image]

Comment: Is your issue with how to enter the details into your software or are you having trouble reading the call-out?

Answer (score 7):

Let's break it down:

5x - There are 5 of these holes, with the same dimension. You should be able to spot these fairly easily, as any similar holes with no dimensions on them.

M4x0.7 - These holes have a Metric Thread, with 4mm outer diameter, and 0.7mm pitch. This is the "M4 Coarse" standard.

↧ 6.3 - The holes are 6.3mm deep. This is the 'full diameter' depth, and not the drill depth, unless otherwise stated. See page 11 here: https://shop.bsigroup.com/upload/Standards%20&%20Publications/Manufacturing/BIP2155-Chapter1.pdf for more details

MAX THD DEPTH - The thread is cut to the maximum depth possible, so will require the use of a 'bottoming tap' during manufacture - See this page for more details on different tap types: https://www.cnccookbook.com/different-types-thread-taps-complete-guide-choosing/

In order to model this hole inside NX, you should use the hole tool, rather than a revolved cut, for example, and then input all these details into the tool. This will ensure that the specification can be automatically added to the drawing.

If you want an actual 3D representation of the threadform, rather than a 'symbolic thread', then you'll need to ask a separate question about modelling that, since this thread is not the right place for that information.